# Fluid image with fixed width/height ratio

Tags: css, image

I want to achieve an effect like the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzBrR.jpg

The image should have a fixed width/height ratio, preferably use percentage instead of rem or em, because they need to lay out in a row and fit exactly inside a container.

And the image should have a line of text below it. Here is what I got so far:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <p>hi there</p>
</div>

.wrapper {
  width: 20%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
  background: lightpink;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not work. However try using 1-100vh. vh is a percentage of the users window, therefore it will scale and be fixed.

Comment: The thing is, I need the height to be the same as the width, if I use vh, it'd be relative to the viewport, and if the page gets resized to half wide, then it'd distort the design. But if I use vmin, then it's not supported in IE 9 and 10

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be as follows.
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/400" /></div>
  <p>hi there</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
p {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du3wfLbu/1/)

Comment: I need to strictly enforce the height of the image (even though it's served from CDN with resize functionality, sometimes the resulting image is just not the specified size), and I don't think your solution would work